# I came across this question and the answers. I'm having similar challenge but i tried the answer to non-365 office users but could not get it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

this data set below. It has 3 columns (PTQ, % Growth, $ Growth) that all need ranked individually then summed up and then ranked again for a total power rank of each region. Is there any way I can do this with a single formula? I do this a lot and it would be nice not to have to rank everything individually each time.

[image]

To clarify, I do not want to rank first on one column then another, they all need to be ranked equally together.

Data:

| Region | PTQ | % Growth | $ Growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TR ARIZONA | 103 | 17.5 | 201330 |
| TR IDAHO UTAH | 75.5 | -6.3 | -69976 |
| TR LA HAWAII | 99.4 | 19.2 | 194840 |
| TR LA NORTH | 125 | 32.7 | 241231 |
| TR NORTHERN CALIFORNIA | 102.3 | 26.2 | 308824 |
| TR NORTHWEST | 91.1 | -0.6 | -4801 |
| TR SAN FRANSISCO | 76.9 | -16.7 | -158387 |
| TR SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA | 106.9 | 30.8 | 495722 |
| TR TUCSON | 100.3 | 7.6 | 34888 |

Comment: So rank each column then sum the ranking results to calculate the single ranking.

Comment: I see the same picture

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same layout as P.b., in `I4`:

`=1+SUMPRODUCT(N(MMULT(CHOOSE({1,2,3},RANK(C$4:C$12,C$4:C$12),RANK(D$4:D$12,D$4:D$12),RANK(E$4:E$12,E$4:E$12)),{1;1;1})<SUM(RANK(C4,C$4:C$12),RANK(D4,D$4:D$12),RANK(E4,E$4:E$12))))`

and copied down.

Comment: Shorter than mine. Very creative including `MMULT/CHOOSE/{1;1;1}`. Something to remember.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite challenging in older Excel, but possible nonetheless:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX(
MMULT(--(RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12)>=TRANSPOSE(RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12))),ROW($C$4:$C$12)^0),ROW($A1))
-SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(--(RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12)>=TRANSPOSE(RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12))),ROW($C$4:$C$12)^0)
=INDEX(MMULT(--(RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12)>=TRANSPOSE(RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12))),ROW($C$4:$C$12)^0),
ROW($A1))))+1
,"")
```

(requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`)

[image]

Explanation:
First an array is made of the sum of the 3 rankings:
`RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12)`
This results in your so called Rank Sum - array.

Then - since `RANK` requires a range, not an array, we need an alternative to create a ranking of the array: `MMULT` can do that.

`MMULT(RankSum>=RankSum,ROW(RankSum)^0)` creates an array of the ranked RankSum, however. If 2 are ranked equally - for instance rank 1 - it's rank both as 2, not 1. Therefore I used `SUMPRODUCT` to calculate the number of items in the calculated `MMULT`-array that equal the indexed `MMULT`-array result as an alternative to `COUNTIF`, which is also limited to take a Range, not Array. So `MMULTarray-SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULTarray=IndexedMMULTarray))` is your end result.

Calculation is based on your data being in `B4:E12` and formula above is entered (with `ctrl+shift+enter`) in a cell in row 4 and copied down; `I4` in the shared screenshot.

Even though this formula answers your question, I doubt this is what you thought what it would be. Changing the range to a different range by itself could be very teasing. And calculating the rankings manually and sum/rank them is probably easier to maintain. You may make it more dynamical by adding INDEX in the ranges.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborative answer. But please I'm interested in the rank for individual columns just like in the picture above. I'm not interested in the power rank, please. I tried it it didn't work. Please help out. Thanks in advance

Comment: They can be found in the formula: `RANK(C$4:C$12,C$4:C$12)` or for the sum: `RANK($C$4:$C$12,$C$4:$C$12)+RANK($D$4:$D$12,$D$4:$D$12)+RANK($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12)`

Comment: PS what do you mean by "it didn't work"? Wrong result, or error? What result/error? Did you enter the formula using `ctrl+shift+enter`